# Prevent automatic conversion of single column to vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:
`df = data.frame(a=1:3, b=2:4, c=3:5)`

I am selecting columns from that data frame using something akin to:
`df[, c(T, F, T)]`

This works fine as long as there are at least two columns to be returned; but, if I do this for example:
`df[, c(T, F, F)]`

... I suddenly only get a vector instead of a data.frame.

Normally this would be fine (or even desired), but since I need the result to be a data.frame at a later point, this completely messes up my scripts.

Is there a way I can prevent R from doing this automatic conversion to a vector for single-column selections?

Comment: do be careful with the `T`/`F` shortcuts for `TRUE`/`FALSE` -- if you ever happen to use `T` or `F` as a user-defined variable things can get very confusing ...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This one is pretty simple. Append `, drop = FALSE` to your subsetting.

E.g.

`df[, c(T, F, F), drop = FALSE]`

Also works for matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Also without the comma, i.e. df[c(T,F,F)], returns a dataframe but it sounds like you have cases where the new dataframe can have one or more columns.   So use the drop option abovee