# converting data.table to matrix and removing column

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a data.table with, say, five rows

```
d <- data.table(rnorm(5),rnorm(5),rnorm(5))
```

which I can convert to a matrix and remove the first column,

```
m <- as.matrix(d)[,-1]
```

and then index using `m[cbind(r,c)]` where `r` and `c` change at each iteration.

I noticed that when `d` has only one row and I convert it,

```
d <- data.table(rnorm(1),rnorm(1),rnorm(1))
m <- as.matrix(d)[,-1]
```

`m` is of class `numeric` and indexing `m[cbind(1,r)]` no longer works. This appears to be due to the `[,-1]`, otherwise `m` is of class `matrix` and indexing works just fine.

Does anyone know where this discontinuity comes from and whether there is a different way of removing the first column that does not cause this problem?

Comment: Add `drop = FALSE`. This has nothing to do with "data.table".

Comment: Exactly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737452/prevent-automatic-conversion-of-single-column-to-vector for this.